# Is there a way to publish messages to AMQP-Azure with O-Auth Token instead of username and password

Tags: azure, amqp, webmethods

- In our current AMQP implementation, we keep the JNDI configurations which contains username and password. Is there a way we can use OAuth instead of static username and Password

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [AMQP protocol Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide#connections-and-sessions) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15135775) thread. As of now AMQP Won't support O-Auth it will be supported only through SASL.
[image]